Long word using only 4 letters
I'm thinking of a 13-letter word that only uses 4 distinct letters. What is it?
Bonus if you can find any longer.


SENSELESSNESS contains just the letters S, E, N and L and is 13 letters long

For the bonus:

The plural form SENSELESSNESSES is 15 letters long


Sensible answer.

Nice find. I was trying to remember 13-letter words which only had rot13(REFG va gur ubcrf gung V pbhyq znxr fbzrguvat yvxr n srznyr grez gung raqrq va -GERFFRF), but as it turns out that wasn't the right strategy and looking back I'm not surprised.
